# Gradle .lock files not removed when stopping build manually

Tags: command-line, gradle, build, locking, ubuntu-12.04

When running gradle build from command line and manually terminating with Ctrl+Z, the .lock files, generated by gradle aren't removed. During the next build, I get a build failure with the following message:

```
.....
> Timeout waiting to lock artifact cache (...). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: ...
.....
```

When I kill the process and run build again, the message doesn't change. Even the process ID remains the same.

Is there a recommended way of stopping a gradle task from command line? Otherwise, is it possible to clean the hanging .lock files?

Comment: Funny, I don't have this issue at all on ubuntu and the latest gradle version. Which gradle are you using?

Comment: @frhd it's Gradle 2.0

Comment: 1. I always CTRL+C the build and there is no lock file. I'm not aware of a different way of cancelling a command line process :) 2. You can manually delete the `.lock` file. Of course, that leaves the question why you have the file in the first place.

Comment: Can you delete the `.lock` file and try again running & cancelling the build? Maybe it was just a hiccup.

Comment: The build isn't always successful after deleting the .lock file. Though when closing the terminal the issue resolves. But this still doesn't answer the question of terminating the build correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using the latest gradle version? 2.0 is pretty dated.

Answer (score 14):

Clear with a command:

```
find . -name "*.lock" | xargs rm
```

### MAC

```
find ~/.gradle/ -name "*.lock" | xargs rm
```

### LINUX

```
find ~/.gradle/ -name "*.lock" | xargs rm
```

Comment: Ran into a build issue after deleting gradle cache manually. I tried lots of things but this was the one that seemed to work.

Answer (score 4):

**1.** When running your non-[daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) build in one terminal, you can stop it in another terminal simply with

```
gradle --stop
```

**2.** The `.lock` file should be cleaned up whenever a non-daemon build is terminated correctly within the same context. If not, you can delete it manually.

I recommend using the latest [gradle](http://gradle.org/) version.

Comment: Tried gradle -stop, but it's saying that no Gradle deamons are running.

Comment: 1. Have you used `gradle -stop` with the same build file? 2. Was the build running at that time?

Comment: The build was running, and I ran the command from the same directory in the second terminal.

Comment: `find . -name ".lock" | xargs rm`